# Is there a way to get @ResponseBody-type behaviour using ModelAndView?

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-mvc, controller, response

One thing I think Rails gets right in terms of its controller design is that you can use your `index` controller action for both the listings, as well as searches, and even ajax calls because you don't have to specify a return type in a typical way.

However, with Spring, because I have to either return `ModelAndView` for a more traditional action, I cannot easily return pure json. I find that I often have to create multiple actions for ajax calls that are basically the same... but because the different annotations and return types required for ajax and non-ajax cases, I have to have 2 controller actions.

Is there a way to get Spring to work with ajax without using annotations like `@RequestBody`? Can I have 1 controller action that returns `ModelAndView`, and will work for even ajax calls that don't require views?

I really would like to avoid `@RequestBody` altogether. Not only does it cause me to duplicate controller actions that are essentially the same, thus bloating up my RESTful interface, but it also makes them harder to test using the `HandlerAdapter` since you always have to use `ModelAndView` anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done by using a `ViewResolver` that would delegate rendering of the response to different `View` implementations depending on some properties of the request.

Spring already has `MarshallingView` and `MappingJacksonJsonView` to render XML and JSON responses. Moreover, Spring has [`ContentNegotiatingViewResolver`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M2/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/ContentNegotiatingViewResolver.html) for exactly that purpose, though its logic looks quite complicated and fragile.

So, you can either use `ContentNegotiatingViewResolver` or create you own `ViewResolver` to solve this problem.